Page numbering disappears when changing orientation from portrait to landscape
In my following script the page numbering disappears when changing the document orientation:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{typearea}

\title{My document}

\begin{document}
    
    \newpage
    \section*{Section 1}
    
    Some text...
    
    \newpage
    \section*{Section 2}
    \KOMAoptions{paper={landscape},pagesize}
    Some text...
    
\end{document}

Is it possible to show the page number after changing the orientation from the portrait to landscape?

Is using typearea critical or are you open to other approaches for landsscape pages?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, it is possible to solve this by typearea, I found the answer)

Such problem could be solved by adjusting DIV parameter. In my example in the post I just set DIV=10.
By the way, the most comprehensive description of what DIV means is very well described in this post.
